# STEAM restarts game download after PC restart

Tags: steam

This problem emerged recently (never had this before). I already had PUBG downloaded completely then while i was downloading its recent update my pc unexpectedly shutdown and when i opened it, pubg restarted to download (the whole game). and now every time i pause download and shutdown my pc, the  download restarts from 0 even though i paused the download and then shutdown the PC. I've tried to google the problem but didn't find any solution. Plz guide me with a solution because downloading the game again and again is very annoying and frustrating and i have crossed my limit to endure it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can either let it finish and see what happens or you can verify the integrity of the game files inatalled because there might be a corruption.